# Base64 coded attachments to e-mails in Public Record Request from City Government

Tags: base64, email-attachments

In a public record request to a city government, I have gotten back a number of records that are .txt format of e-mails with attachments appearing to be base64. The e-mail attachments are jpegs, pdf, png, or doc in base64 a shorter example is below. The government official claim "The records we released to you are in the form that was available, including the file you noted. From what I have been told, it is likely garbled computer coding. We have no other version of those records."

Questions:

Does someone have to intentionally work at saving the e-mail and attachments in this way so that they are unreadable, thus making the information not public (hiding it)?

or is this something that can plausibly happen in saving "garbled computer coding"?
If it is plausible that a computer does it, how?

Is there a way of decoding it?
I have tried a number of online decoding with various settings and have been unsuccessful.

I have done a number of public record requests from this city and department in the past and have never gotten such .txt documents. The public record request is around a city contract that is problematic.

---

```
From: "Steinberg, David (DPW)" <david.steinberg@sfdpw.org>
To: "Goldberg, Jonathan (DPW)" <jonathan.goldberg@sfdpw.org>
Sent: Fri, 17 May 2019 20:40:36 +0000
Subject: Re: SOTF - Education, Outreach and Training Committee, May 21, 2019 hearing



   
       ----boundary-LibPST-iamunique-566105023_-_-
        Content-Type: image/jpeg
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
        Content-ID: <image002.jpg@01D50CB4.2B093D10>
        Content-Disposition: attachment; 
                filename*=utf-8''image002.jpg;
                filename="image002.jpg"
        
         /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAoHBwkHBgoJCAkLCwoMDxkQDw4ODx4WFxIZJCAmJSMg
        IyIoLTkwKCo2KyIjMkQyNjs9QEBAJjBGS0U+Sjk/QD3/2wBDAQsLCw8NDx0QEB09KSMpPT09PT09
        PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT09PT3/wAARCABJAFEDASIA
        AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
        AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
        ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
        p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
        AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
        BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
        U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
        uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDKooqa
        FY47qIXiSiHcPMVRhtuecZ716ZgRojSOqIpZ2OAo6k0+G2muBIYYZJBEu+Taudi9yfSum1bwlDa6
        ENa0q7mlh4lVXGGVD0ORzkcVf8ExwaxHqPnb4bsxeVLLE20SI38RHTcMHnvWTqrl5kUo62OO07T5
        9VvY7S0VWmkztDNgcDJ5qB0aN2RhhlJUj3Fdp4N0LT/7YZ5bx/t9nK4FtwOBwGz3GCK5/WmhsfFl
        20FvE0UNxkQtyjY6g+xOaaqXk0hWsjJorutb0XS9R8OzaxZReVdpGssiQjCklQeVPbBzkVwtVCak
        gasFFKFJViMHb1Hf649KSrEFFFFAE9jMba/t5gMlJFOAAc8+/FaPiO7a5uLdXl8xUQhcyb3UFj8p
        OAcgY45rKiDtKgiBMhYbQPWtb+3tRe9ubh4rWedwryu8CvgLjGOwA9qzktboaOsuNXNtbaroscAE
        NtpweBm5aQbRkkdB16exrN+H979lt9UXaD8isDjvhv8ACuZe7vvtD30hcvMjAu3IKNlSOe3OPal0
        ++vNMhmmtSqpIuxmbB6EHgHr1/I1n7P3Wu4+bU6HwPe/a/FiMyhMWhjRe+Bjqe5965vUZHutYu3d
        gXedyT0HU80+zm1DSLuNrUtFM5CqBg7j6fqOPzqNGujb3ESR5EkgEz7fmzydpPYZBOPUVajaV0K+
        h1eka2n9iw2RCRpeySWZduvESqhPtkj6Zrm9F0oahrFvaXLNDC0pieQDgMATtB6ZOMfjUZurloLP
        zI4mggfMSbVXcSRnOOTnHWrdtr2raf5ksMixxGd3aMouwuSM8dTjj6UlFxvbqO99zvNYtLPQ9I8j
        SbexivJQY4VlUbpePmAJ6nHr1OBXljI0Z2OrKw4IYYIrS1jUNQ1q+SS+SPziuFVFAwPfnPvzVCcy
        mU/aGYyYHLNk4xxz6YopQcVqEncjooorYkltYpZ7uKK3jMkzMAiDua0prTV7RZ7p7UKhA81l2uAM
        Y5wScc8n9aj8Nf8AIy6d/wBdhT7ObTtJeWe2uJriZoniWPyPLX5hjLHPIGelZSbvZDRTD3Taa+Fz
        aqyxlsfdbkgfU/0pmLhtObAb7Ksm1iDxvI6H8BVyAf8AFI3mOQt7CT7DYwoi48J3BPRr6MA+uI2z
        /Onf8wJY7PWLwQ3aQbwQxicsgyDxwCarJJfx6k8AiK3ckmxomTBLEYxj8fz5q5fLpp07R/t5ut/2
        T/liExt8x/XvVmYs/jTTJsgxTNbvCec+XwF3Z/i45qFIdjAeR1Cxui74TtDEfMMHp6dalZrk2Ekp
        j/0eaUqZP9v7xA54/L8ahu2H2245H+ufv/tGtF/+RPj/AOv9v/RYrTohDLW0v9QY3VvbIVyVeRiE
        RyRyCWIBP0qrfQ3FvcmK6h8mRVACY4C44x7e9XfEHXT1X/j1FnGYB26fP+O7Oays5A/SiOuoMKKK
        KsRZ037UNSt/sH/H1vHldPvfjxSrpl42pf2etuxu9xTysjOev06VBDM9tPHPEcSRMHU+4Oa9EuYo
        7bU7jxVGoMJ04Sx+hlPAH5Y/Ospz5WUlc4rT49UtNVeys4z9rcmKSBgrB8ckEHg9M1M1rrWu3TWq
        WxkNqShiiVUjiPfp8ueK68Qpbajd+Kto8l9PWWMjp5jDBH6D86xNRnmtfh9phtHZEuZWa6kQ4LOS
        eCfr/IVCnd6IdjPvX1vQoIIL62SOKNSsTSwRyDGScBsH1JxUo0HxNcXceo/ZJZJsrIkhdO33cDPT
        2qzo80t54H16O9dpLWFA0LOc7XxnAJ98fnWvrmnxajcaLE2s/YJntkVIwrZc8cgggfnSc7OwWuc4
        JtdvbybT/skRuirGSM2sSNjuckD161QtLbUL+xlt7aMyW1sxnk5UBDjGSx9h0ruLW8W9+IrRKrqb
        Wza3Z5B8zkEfN+tZus29uPB8kOg3HmW1pcEX2BzKf7xPcA/h+VCnrawWMjRLXXruyK6dai4tAxIW
        ZEZA3fbu7/Ss/V1v0vyuqIyXAUDaygYXtgDjH0rcsta0q98PWmlandXWnvbE7JoSdjdeTj61meJd
        KuNJ1JEuLo3ayxh4pyTll6DP0q4v3tRPYyKKKK2JCtSTxDeyeH00dtn2ZCCDg7sA5xnPTNZdFJpP
        cDUfxDeyeH00djH9mQ5BAO4jOcE56Zo0nxFeaRFJBGIp7WQ5eCddyE+vtWXRS5I2tYd2a2reI7zV
        rVbRkhtrRTkQW6bVJ9T61DqWt3WqS2kkwRHtUCRmMEcA5BPPXis+ihQS6Cuzb/4Su9GtnVRDbC5M
        XlNhTtYepGetVNK1q50h7gwLHIlyhSWOUEqw+mfc/nWfRS5I7WHdm5YeKrixso7RrKxuIYs+WJos
        lec9aoarq11rV59pvGUuF2qqjCovoBVKimoRTuhXYUUUVQH/2Q==
        
        
        ----boundary-LibPST-iamunique-566105023_-_---
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I got the image by copying your base64 data to a file and

```
base64 -d file > image.jpeg
```

on my Debian/Linux.

RFC 2045 section 6 says binary data are to be encoded in US-ASCII characters
so that it's quite normal images are encoded by base64 although GUI email reader
would not show you raw data.

When you see such raw data, it means somebody might copy and paste other emails blindly, still it less likely happen. (Obviously your example is part of multipart message, but not complete.)

Decode service on web is available, for example, [here](https://www.base64decode.org).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to replicate, got the same image. 
I take it I can do the same thing with pdf, and doc. 
"When you see such raw data, it means somebody might copy and paste other emails blindly, still, it less likely to happen."
My guess it this happens only when a person copies and saves messages and records in a .txt form, since txt can not show a pdf or jpeg or doc it converts it to base64?

They could save records in their original form ie .pdf which is easier than what they are doing.
I ask this because it has legal implications.